# Require to Import with initialization paramater

Tags: javascript, nestjs, commonjs

Sorry if this is a repost/duplicate.

I'm needing some guidance with converting this require statement to an import statement.

I'm using the mailchimp API which has a require statement documented.

`const mailchimpClient = require("mailchimp_transactional")("YOUR_API_KEY");`

I need to convert this to an import statement as I'm using NestJS and eslint doesn't like require.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import mailchamp from 'mailchimp_transactional'

const mailchimpClient = mailchimp("YOUR_API_KEY")
```

or

```
import * as mailchamp from 'mailchimp_transactional'

const mailchimpClient = mailchimp("YOUR_API_KEY")
```

depending on how your tsconfig looks like.